# FacesContext defaultFacesContext null when rendering custom component

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf, upgrade, jsf-1.2

We have a templated header content that uses a custom JSF component that cannot push to the EL as it cannot get the faces context attributes.

I have converted some old POJOs that extends a SimpleFormController class in Spring 3.0 for Spring 4.3 annotations following:

[Link to example Spring Simple Form Controller conversion](https://dzone.com/articles/converting-spring)

I have debugged the FacesContext class to see why and the jsf-api 2.0 class uses the defaultFacesContext to get the attributes but its null.
Prior to upgrade this was library jsf-api 1.2_15

```
AppConfig.java


@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver()
    {

    UrlBasedViewResolver res = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    res.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
    res.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    res.setSuffix(".xhtml");

    return res;
}


 FacesContext.java

/**
 * <p class="changed_added_2_0">Return a mutable <code>Map</code> 
 * representing the attributes associated wth this
 * <code>FacesContext</code> instance.  This <code>Map</code> is 
 * useful to store attributes that you want to go out of scope when the
 * Faces lifecycle for the current request ends, which is not always the same 
 * as the request ending, especially in the case of Servlet filters
 * that are invoked <strong>after</strong> the Faces lifecycle for this
 * request completes.  Accessing this <code>Map</code> does not cause any 
 * events to fire, as is the case with the other maps: for request, session, and 
 * application scope.  When {@link #release()} is invoked, the attributes
 * must be cleared.</p>
 * 
 * <div class="changed_added_2_0">
 * 
 * <p>The <code>Map</code> returned by this method is not associated with
 * the request.  If you would like to get or set request attributes,
 * see {@link ExternalContext#getRequestMap}.  
 * 
 * <p>The default implementation throws
 * <code>UnsupportedOperationException</code> and is provided
 * for the sole purpose of not breaking existing applications that extend
 * this class.</p>
 *
 * </div>
 * 
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this method is called after
 *  this instance has been released
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */
public Map<Object, Object> getAttributes() {

    if (defaultFacesContext != null) {
        return defaultFacesContext.getAttributes();
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

}
```

.... getting ERROR:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at 
    javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes(FacesContext.java:141)
    at 

  javax.faces.component.UIComponent.popComponentFromEL(UIComponent.java:1722)
    at 

  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2022)
    at 

  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1691)
    at 

  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:403)
```

We'd like the component to register and render to the browser.
Is there a change in the way I need to configure the jsf veiw handler with jsf-api 2.0?

Comment: Maybe the page is not accessed through the jsf servlet filter? Check the **FULL** stacktrace (and always post it)

Comment: So I finished updating to jsf-api 2.0.11 and also the jsf-impl to 2.0.11 and the old 1.2.15 miss match looks to be why the defaultFacesContext wasn’t populated.